# Defining a width that fills remaining horizontal space for text fields in hyperref forms environment

Tags: positioning

This code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[showframe,headheight=2in,headsep=0.1in,left=0.8in,right=0.8in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent\textbf{DESCRIPTION OF ACTIVITY}\raisebox{-2pt}{\TextField[name=description,width=4.3in]{~}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image]

Notice that the text field box did not end at the right margin. This results to ugly alignment of the boxes after typing several lines with text fields. I could have used `\hfill` before the text field but that will leave ugly white space between DESCRIPTION... and the text field.

So, to my question: How can I define a width, remwidth, such that I can write

```
\noindent\textbf{DESCRIPTION OF ACTIVITY}\raisebox{-2pt}{\TextField[name=description,width=remwidth]{}}
```

so that the text field box stops exactly at the right margin rule?

I would appreciate it very much if the the answer would include an explanation of what is happening at every step.

**Edit: October 15, 2012** I edited the question since the problem is really about the `\TextField` command and the `hyperref` package putting a padding in it as noted in the comments. The other part of my question on defining a width command that I can use elsewhere is actually solved by `\linewidth`, which I just learned last night even after 3 years of using LaTeX. The question [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize) clarified its use for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The mandatory argument to `\TextField` is the text that precedes the box. It's sufficient to measure it (and cut out something).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength\TextFieldLength
\newcommand\TextFieldFill[2][]{%
  \setlength\TextFieldLength{\linewidth}%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#2 }%
  \addtolength\TextFieldLength{-\dimen0}%
  \addtolength\TextFieldLength{-2.22221pt}%
  \TextField[#1,width=\TextFieldLength]{\raisebox{2pt}{#2 }}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{Form}
\noindent\TextFieldFill[name=description]{\textbf{DESCRIPTION OF ACTIVITY}}

\noindent\TextFieldFill[name=procrastination]{\textbf{WAYS TO PROCRASTINATE}}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` and `geometry` packages are just to provide text and the frame. The 2.22221pt excess has been determined from the `Overfull \hbox` message that one gets without it.

One can get rid of this adjustment by doing

```
\newcommand\TextFieldFill[2][]{%
  \setlength\TextFieldLength{\linewidth}%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#2 }%
  \addtolength\TextFieldLength{-\dimen0}%
  \TextField[#1,width=\TextFieldLength]{\raisebox{2pt}{#2}}%
}
```

because the macro that is called by `\TextField` adds one between the text and the box (thanks to Heiko Oberdiek for pointing out this).

[image]

Comment: +1 for WAYS TO PROCRASTINATE. i was about to sleep when i saw that and laughed hard :D

Comment: @hpesoj626 You can see that the field is wider than the one for the description. `:-)`

Comment: @egreg An additional space is added by `\LayoutTextField`, then `\dimen0` if fixed by \settowidth{\dimen0}{#2 \space}` and you can get rid of the `2.2221pt` that also might change depending on the glue of the text description.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, Tex does not warn of an overfull `\hbox` with your suggestion but the end of the text field will cross the right margin with `showframe` option in `geometry` package. Why is that?

Comment: Some `hyperref` drivers add a link margin of `1pt`: `\addtolength\TextFieldLength{-1pt}`. See also [`\ref` with tight box surrounding the reference](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77595/16967).

Comment: @hpesoj626 And adding `\kern1pt` after the text field that is shortened by `\addtolength\TextFieldLength{-1pt}`.

Answer (score 9):

It's easiest if you measure the earlier text then you can subtract its width from `\linewidth`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[showframe,headheight=2in,headsep=0.1in,left=0.8in,right=0.8in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newbox\formbox

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
\setbox\formbox\hbox{\textbf{DESCRIPTION OF ACTIVITY}}\usebox\formbox
\raisebox{-2pt}{\TextField[name=description, width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\formbox\relax]{}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This produces an overfull `\hbox`.

Comment: This will require me to type \setbox\formbox\hbox... in every line though. Even with copy and paste, this becomes tedious after several lines :)

Comment: I don't know why but it does not work for me.

Comment: @hpesoj626 using David's idea you can define a two-argument command to do the work for you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes I suspect hyperref is padding the box, but checking where would require reading the manual. But it seems egreg has read the manual already.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I had done the same thing, but I'm still not sure what kind of padding is inserted by `hyperref`, always causing a slight overfull `\hbox` (`4.44333pt`).

Comment: a decent solution you may find here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290934/26295