# How to make it so that my 2 tables fill the entire page?

Tags: formatting

Been working on a pars cover sheet for my job. Here what the result look's like for now. Im trying to make it look like the picture I shared but im strugglin. How would I make it so that my 2 tabularx fill all the page like on the picture I shared ?

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.jpg}

Les XXXXX XXXX XXXXXX inc.\\
address \\
City, state\\
Postal code \\
TEL:(XXX) XXX-XXXX\\
    FAX: (XXX) 655-XXXX\\
e-mail: nic@XXXXX.com
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \TextField{TO:} & \TextField{SHIPMENT:} \\
    \TextField{FROM:} & \TextField{ORDER:} \\
    \TextField{DATE:}
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \TextField{PARS:}\\

    \TextField{PORT OF ENTRY:}\\

    \TextField{DATE OF ARRIVAL:}\\

    \TextField{TIME OF ARRIVAL:}\\

    \TextField{COMMENTS:}
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

[image: Old template made in Excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77633/42803):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments} % for sample image only

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} % add line spacing

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % generates underlined text

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in}
    
% source:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77633/42803
\newlength\TextFieldLength
\newcommand\TextFieldFill[1]{%
  \setlength\TextFieldLength{\linewidth}%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1 }%
  \addtolength\TextFieldLength{-\dimen0}%
  \uline{\TextField[width=\TextFieldLength]{\raisebox{2pt}{#1}}}%
  \vspace{6mm}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}

Les XXXXX XXXX XXXXXX inc.\\
address \\
City, state\\
Postal code \\
TEL:(XXX) XXX-XXXX\\
    FAX: (XXX) 655-XXXX\\
e-mail: nic@XXXXX.com
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultHeightofText{14pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \TextFieldFill{TO: } & \TextFieldFill{SHIPMENT: } \\
    \TextFieldFill{FROM: } & \TextFieldFill{ORDER: } \\
    \TextFieldFill{DATE: } & \\[1.5cm]
    \TextFieldFill{\textbf{PARS:} } & \\
    \TextFieldFill{PORT OF ENTRY: } & \\
    \TextFieldFill{DATE OF ARRIVAL: } & \\
    \TextFieldFill{TIME OF ARRIVAL: } & \\
    \TextFieldFill{COMMENTS: } & \\
    \TextFieldFill{} & \\
    \TextFieldFill{} & \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- With `tabularray`-->`rows=2cm`, you can adjust
- `\TextField[width=5cm,height=1cm,borderstyle=U]{TO:}` in the doc `hyperref`
- `\vfill` fills the remaining vertical space on the current page

  ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
   %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669197/how-to-make-it-so-that-my-2-tables-fill-the-entire-page
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   %\usepackage{tabularx}
   \usepackage{tabularray}
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{margin=0.5in}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}

   Les XXXXX XXXX XXXXXX inc.\\
   address \\
   City, state\\
   Postal code \\
   TEL:(XXX) XXX-XXXX\\
       FAX: (XXX) 655-XXXX\\
   e-mail: nic@XXXXX.com
   \end{center}

   \vfill
   \Large
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tblr}
       {
       rows=2cm,   
       width=0.75\linewidth,
       colspec={*{2}{X[r]}},
       }               
       \TextField[width=5cm,height=1cm,borderstyle=U]{TO:}&\TextField{SHIPMENT:}\\
       \TextField{FROM:} & \TextField{ORDER:} \\
       \TextField{DATE:}\\
       \TextField{PARS:}
   \end{tblr}   

   \vfill
   \begin{tblr}
       {
       rows=1cm,
       width=0.5\linewidth,
       colspec={X[r]},
       } 
       \TextField{PORT OF ENTRY:}\\
       \TextField{DATE OF ARRIVAL:}\\
       \TextField{TIME OF ARRIVAL:}\\
       \TextField{COMMENTS:}
   \end{tblr}   
   \end{center}
   \end{document}
  ```