# Letters look misaligned

Tags: fonts

At one point I did something to Miktex, the result is miss aligned letters. At least that is my impression. I have two example photos:[image: CHOL ja SBP.]
and [image: tarvittavat]. The first photo: to my eyes H is lower than C and O beside it. The second: v letter is under r. They look wrong. Any document that I write is full of similar misaligned letters. What have I done!

Comment: First, I think it is just a viewer issue.  Does the misalignment persist when you zoom in on the images in the PDF?  I am thinking not.  As to what caused it, perhaps `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` without also doing a `\usepackage{lmodern}` maybe?

Comment: Bless you! I used the package you suggested and all is fine.

Comment: I vote against closing this as off-topic (at least for the reason stated in the current close vote): this question very much *does* “fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems”.

Comment: What viewer did you get these results in? TeX decides the positions of the characters (correctly), but it is your viewer that converts those positions characters (using the font) into pixels on screen… I wonder what viewer does such a bad job.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: This is most certainly viewer-based, until proven otherwise.

Comment: @Werner Yes, but viewers are very much part of the TeX ecosystem. How to generate output from TeX (and related systems) such that a viewer displays it properly is the heart of many questions on this site and we don't have a consistent policy of closing such questions, e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391004/link-boxes-obscure-punctuation). (I even remember a nice [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex) that was *entirely* about viewers; was a lot of fun to investigate that one.)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Testing
\end{document}
```

[image]

Add just `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

[image]

While `T1` encoding gives one access to a wider range of font glyphs, the problem here is that LaTeX's default font (computer modern) is designed only for the older `OT1` encoding.  When one switches to `T1` encoding, a bitmap version is constructed and used.  The remedy is to use a font that was designed for `T1` encoding.  The `lmodern` font is a version of computer modern, specifically designed for `T1` encoding.

Therefore, also add `\usepackage{lmodern}`:

[image]

Comment: I don't get your results (bitmap font) with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, if I compile with `pdflatex`. Nor do I get it with `latex` followed by either viewing the DVI file (in Skim), or `dvips` + viewing the PS , or `dvipdfmx` + viewing the PDF. How can you get bitmap fonts? :-)

Comment: Oh but I use TeX Live on Mac, not MikTeX, so perhaps the config is different on Windows. Nevermind.

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup if you have no type1 versions of T1 cmr

Comment: If bitmaps are used with T1-encoding then you either don't have the cm-super package installed, or you have a quite all tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have never known it to behave differently in all the years I have been TeXing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Must be a MikTeX default, because it has always been that way, as I said to David.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it's also the default in a full texlive install