# Which texlive package can give me hyperref functionality?

Tags: hyperref, texlive

So far I've installed `sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers` and `sudo apt-get install texlive-science`, but I don't want to `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` because of the [huge](http://%5Cusepackage%7Bhyperref%7D) download.

Using `\usepackage{hyperref}` gives me some errors.
[image]

So obviously hyperref is located in some other package.
The [readme and manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) of hyperref didn't give me any clues.

[This website](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latex-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) provides some clues, but doesn't specify which of the packages can give hyperref.
texlive-base - 136 MB
texlive-latex-recommended - 177 MB
texlive - 240 MB
texlive-latex-extra - 404 MB
texlive-full - 4714 MB

So could anyone please help with this info? which texlive package should a person install to get [hyperref functionality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528673/what-are-the-coloured-rectangles-in-research-papers)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking about? Hyperref is installed on your system. But you have some problems in your code.

Comment: You mean hyperref is part of texlive-publishers or texlive-science? I'm getting those errors only if I include `\usepackage{hyperref}`. If I remove that line, the LaTeX compiles fine. The LaTeX was generated via LyX, so I'm sure there's no other error.

Comment: The error messages suggest that `hyperref` is installed on your system (that is to say it is part of one of the `texlive-...` packages you already have installed). You already have `hyperref`, so for the problem at hand it is not relevant which package contains it. The error messages suggest that something in your document related to `hyperref` usage is wrong. In order to help with that we would need to know details about your document. Ideally in the form of a short example document that reproduces the error, a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: But just to answer your question: In Debian (which is what Ubuntu for example is based on), `hyperref` is in `texlive-latex-base`, see https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/texlive-latex-base. If you are using Ubuntu you can double check that `hyperref.sty` is indeed part of `texlive-latex-base` for your version at https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/texlive-latex-base under "file list": https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/all/texlive-latex-base/filelist.